# What is the expected number of biased coin tosses for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, probability

Suppose I have a biased coin. When flipped, the probability of yielding heads is 4/5.

To fake a fair toss, I pursue the following algorithm that models this situation. Suppose `True` models heads, and `False` represents tails.

P(doUnfairFlip() = 0) = 0.8 
and 
P(doUnfairFlip() = 1) = 0.2

```
def fakeFairToss():
    flip1 = 0
    flip2 = 0
    while (flip1 == flip2):
        flip1 = doUnfairFlip()
        flip2 = doUnfairFlip()
    return (True if (flip1 == 0) else False)
```

It makes use of the fact that one is equally likely to get a heads-tails or a tails-heads after two coin flips.

How many individual flips of this biased coin should I expect every time this function runs?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying P(rand() % 2 = 0) = 0.8, P(rand() % 2 = 1) = 0.2?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified it. P(doUnfairFlip() = 0) = 0.8 and P(doUnfairFlip() = 1) = 0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The odds of equality are `1/5^2 + 4/5^2 = 17/25 = 68%`, assuming samples from `doUnfairFlip()` are [IID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iid).

Instead of thinking of loop iterations per function invocation, we can look at the situation as a unbounded sequence of iterations occasionally "punctuated" by function returns.  Notice a function return occurs precisely when equality fails, `100 - 68 = 32%` of the time.

We can now identify the situation as a discrete [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process), with `lambda = 0.32`.  The mean of corresponding distribution is also `lambda`: we can expect about `0.32` function invocations per loop iteration, or `1.0 / 0.32 = 3.125` iterations per invocation, or `6.25` calls to `doUnfairFlip()` per invocation.

Comment: Just posting to note that another similar route to the same answer is to note that the number of loops is a geometric random variable with p = .32: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution  ...because this is somehow not the highest voted answer despite being the only correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're saying is that

```
P(rand() % 2 = 0) = 0.8
P(rand() % 2 = 1) = 0.2
```

Then the probability of meeting the loop condition is

```
0.8*0.8 + 0.2*0.2 = 0.68
```

You will execute the loop as many times as the expected number of times to get a failure when p = 0.68, which is 3.125. So you should expect to run the loop 3.125 times, and call rand() a total of 6.25 times.

Comment: Probability of looping is 0.8^2 + 0.2^2 = 0.68

Comment: @ElKamina: Good catch, sorry about the calculational error. I see that somebody has already edited the rest of it, taking the correct value 0.68 into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think its about 1.5 runs of the while loop, or 3 calls to rand(). My math may be wrong though.